# How do I reference class variables/methods from nested functions?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.foobar = "foobar";
  }
  bar() {
    let _this = this;
    return function() {
      try {
        alert("Attempt 1: "+foobar);//ReferenceError: foobar is not defined
        myMethod();
      } catch(err) {console.log(err);}
      try {
        alert("Attempt 2: "+this.foobar);//TypeError: this is undefined
        this.myMethod();
      } catch(err) {console.log(err);}
      try{
        alert("Attempt 3: "+_this.foobar);//Works!
        _this.myMethod();
      } catch(err) {console.log(err);}
    }();
  }
  myMethod() {
    alert("myMethod()");
  }
}
new Foo().bar();
```

*The above example is very simplified - the anonymous function inside `bar()` was a jQuery call originally, but for the sake of the question I didn't include that.*

Why don't attempts 1 and 2 work? Do I have to use the _this trick to reference class variables/methods? **How do I reference class variables/methods from nested functions?**

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with how the `this` keyword works in JavaScript? It's value will depend on how the function is called, not in how it is defined. For example, if you do the following:

```js
var dog = {
  greeting:"woof",
  talk:function (){
    console.log(this.greeting);
  }
};

var cat={
  greeting:"meow",
  talk:dog.talk
};

dog.talk();
cat.talk();
```

You will see that  when the talk function is called as a method of an object, that object will be used as the value of `this`.

The same happens with ES6 classes, where class methods are still JavaScript functions and the rules for deciding the value of `this` still apply. If you want to avoid declaring an auxiliar variable, you should look into using `bind`:

```js
var mammal = {
  greeting:"<noise>",
  getTalk:function (){
    return function(){
      console.log(this.greeting);
    };
  },
  getTalkBinded:function (){
    return (function(){
      console.log(this.greeting)
    }).bind(this);
  }
};

var dog={
  greeting:"woof",
  talk:mammal.getTalk(),
  talkBinded:mammal.getTalkBinded()
};

var cat={
  greeting:"meow",
  talk:mammal.getTalk(),
  talkBinded:mammal.getTalkBinded()
};

dog.talk();
cat.talk();
dog.talkBinded();
cat.talkBinded();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning self-execution function execution result and during that function execution `this` it global context(not your class object). to make it work use `() => {}()` arrow function call syntax, as it captures current context, or `function() {  }.bind(this)()`.

Answer (score 0):

See this simple example,

```
function a(){
    this.someProp = 5;
    console.log(this);

    var _this = this;   //so we explicitly store the value of `this` to use in a nested function

    return function(){
        //value of `this` will change inside this function
        this.anotherProp = 6;
        console.log(this);

        //to use the methods and props of original function use `_this`
        console.log(_this)
    }
}

var c = a.call({})  //prints {someProp: 5}
c.call({})    //prints {anotherProps: 6} {someProp: 5}
```